# Which keyName can be used for disk_controller when I create a custom bare metal server without RAID configuration?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I define storageGroups in custom bare metal server ordering, `DISK_CONTROLLER_RAID` can be used as a disk_controller. If I create a custom bare metal server without RAID configuration, do I still need a disk_controller priceId? If yes, which keyName should be used?

Answer (score 0):

For BMS without RAID configuration you need to specify the price id of a Non-Raid disk controller, the keyName is DISK_CONTROLLER_NONRAID.

You can use following REST call to retrieve Non-Raid controllers, change the package 200 if you are using another one.

```
https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/200/getItemPrices?objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"item":{"keyName":"operation":"DISK_CONTROLLER_NONRAID"}}}}
```

I hope this help you.